# Exe build with cmake crashing with an error

Tags: python, cmake, decompiler

i tried to use pycdc https://github.com/zrax/pycdc and i build it using cmake.
when i try to decompile with it a pyc file it printes a few lines of the file and crashes with an error "Debug Assersion Failed!" [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgV7r.png). i couldn't find anything usefull about this error in general. i tried everything and i couldn't make it work

Comment: I suggest you to open an issue on the repository, so that the author can help you.

Comment: If you've generated a Visual Studio solution via cmake for this exe Run the program via VS debugger and click retry; this should effectively treat the failed assertion as a breakpoint allowing you to inspect the stack. Based on the info provided the only thing we can tell for sure without an analysis of the repo is that `std::list` is used incorrectly in the code...